# Continuous ADC readings are corrupted with I2C function calls in STM32 microcontroller

Tags: stm32

**Important Edit**: The issue is solved when I increased the speed of I2C from 400kHz to 1000kHz(Fast Mode Plus). I get expected temperature readings(31 32C) now no outliers like 104C. But dont know why increasing the speed solved the problem.

-end of edit-

I'm using a NUCLEO-F030R8 board and [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0365-stm32f302xbcde-and-stm32f302x68-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) is its reference manual. I also shared the entire code at the end of this question.

In my application, the microcontroller reads and updates the value of a current sensor through I2C protocol at each interrupt of Timer 16 using **HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback**. The microcontroller also calculates the inner chip temperature in continuous ADC mode using **HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback**. (adc1_value[0] and adc1_value[1] is needed to calculate the temperature as you will see in the code)

The I2C current values are read without error but the ADC temperature values fluctuates from 30°C to 145°C.

I noticed this problem occurs when the I2C function **HAL_I2C_Master_Receive** is called during ADC running. So in my code I tried the following:

```
__disable_irq();   // disable all interrupts
HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, SLAVE_ADDR << 1, data_buf, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
__enable_irq();  // enable all interrupts
```

But above didn.t solve the issue. Here below is my entire code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILTER_LENGTH 20
#define TRESHOLD_I2C 2089
#define VREFINT_CAL ((uint16_t*) ((uint32_t) 0x1FFFF7BA)) /* Internal voltage reference, parameter VREFINT_CAL: Raw data acquired at a temperature of 30 DegC (+-5 DegC), VDDA = 3.3 V (+-10 mV). */
#define V25    (float)1.43
#define Avg_slope    (float)0.0043

const uint8_t SLAVE_ADDR = 0x4D;
char msg_int[20];
float Vcc;
float current_val;
float Vsense = 0, Vdda = 0;
float Temperature;
int count = 0;
char msg_scr[20];
float x;
float y;
int16_t read_value;
int16_t moving_filter_out;
int16_t buffer_filter[FILTER_LENGTH];
int16_t counter_filter;
uint32_t sum;
uint16_t adc1_value[2];

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim16;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void);


void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc) {
    if (__HAL_ADC_GET_FLAG(&hadc1, ADC_FLAG_EOC) != RESET) {
        adc1_value[count] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
        count++; // count = 0 --> Vrefint channel & count = 1 --> Temperature channel

        if (count == 2)
            count = 0;

        Vdda = (float) (3.3 * ((float) *VREFINT_CAL / (float) adc1_value[0]));
        Vsense = Vdda * (float) adc1_value[1] / 4095.0;
        Temperature = ((V25 - Vsense) / Avg_slope ) + 25.0;
    }
}

uint16_t current_read_value(void) {
    uint8_t data_buf[2];
    uint16_t temp_data;

    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, SLAVE_ADDR << 1, data_buf, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    temp_data = data_buf[0];
    temp_data = temp_data << 8;
    temp_data = temp_data | data_buf[1];

    return temp_data;
}


int main(void) {

    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();

    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();
    MX_I2C1_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();
    MX_TIM16_Init();

    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim16);
    HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);

    while (1) {

        HAL_Delay(1000);

        uint16_t I2C_value = moving_filter_out;
        current_val = (I2C_value / 4096.0 - 0.5) * 50 * 1000;

        sprintf(msg_int, "%.3f [C]\r\n", Temperature);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) msg_int, strlen(msg_int),
        HAL_MAX_DELAY);

        x = Temperature;
        y = current_val;

    }
}


void SystemClock_Config(void) {
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = { 0 };
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = { 0 };
    RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = { 0 };

    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI
            | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }


    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
            | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C1
            | RCC_PERIPHCLK_TIM16;
    PeriphClkInit.I2c1ClockSelection = RCC_I2C1CLKSOURCE_HSI;
    PeriphClkInit.Tim16ClockSelection = RCC_TIM16CLK_HCLK;
    if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}


static void MX_ADC1_Init(void) {

    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = { 0 };

    hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
    hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
    hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
    hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
    hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
    hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 2;
    hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
    hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
    if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_VREFINT;
    sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
    sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_601CYCLES_5;
    sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
    sConfig.Offset = 0;
    if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }


    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_TEMPSENSOR;
    sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
    if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

}


static void MX_I2C1_Init(void) {

    hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
    hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x0000020B;
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
    hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
    hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
    hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
    hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE)
            != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}


static void MX_TIM16_Init(void) {

    htim16.Instance = TIM16;
    htim16.Init.Prescaler = 3600 - 1;
    htim16.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim16.Init.Period = 10 - 1;
    htim16.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim16.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
    htim16.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void) {

    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 38400;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = { 0 };

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9 | GPIO_PIN_10;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {

    if (htim == &htim16) {

        read_value = current_read_value();

        sum = sum + read_value - buffer_filter[counter_filter];
        moving_filter_out = sum / FILTER_LENGTH;
        buffer_filter[counter_filter] = read_value;
        counter_filter++;
        if (counter_filter == FILTER_LENGTH)
            counter_filter = 0;
    }
}

void Error_Handler(void) {

    __disable_irq();
    while (1) {
    }

}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
}
#endif
```

Comment: If you could tell us more about the sensor and what kinds of errors you're seeing that would be a lot more helpful than 1000-page manual and 300-lines of code.  What are you expecting and what are you actually getting?

Comment: The temperature is read internally by ADC. The issue is when they are used together. If I dont use HAL_I2C_Master_Receive in the interrupt callback the temperature is around 35C as expected. But when I use HAL_I2C_Master_Receive  the temperature swings from 35C  to 145C. Meaning that something between timers or interrupts is effecting each other. The chip I use for I2C is here: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001732e.pdf (It always gives correct value no matter it is used with ADC or not), The ADC readings giving error when it is used with I2C.

Comment: I doubt you need to use interrupts with the adc to read temperature. Use synchronous functions rather than async with callbacks. The other thing to consider is that the callbacks are probably from an interrupt context and you have shared variables between the non interrupt context and your callbacks that aren’t declared volatile and may lack atomic protection.

Comment: What functions are async?